# accessing htaccess protected pages from ubuntu touch browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, .htaccess

I tried to access a webpage, which is password protected by htaccess (apache server ...) from my bq aquaris running Ubuntu touch 5.0.

The browser gave me no options to enter the username/password and displayed the following error:

> The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials or your
>   browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Obviously the latter case applies, but my question is ... is there any way around it? or will I have to wait for the browser to get  that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This was already fixed and should be landed in OTA7, so by next month you should have it delivered in yuor phone